# Filling a grid with buttons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to objective c and trying the learn the basics of creating a UI. In my UIView class, I have created a grid along with buttons, yet those buttons don't actually exist (as far as I can tell). Ideally, when I click a button, the image is supposed to change, but that doesn't happen. Where should I be looking at to fix?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if( self = [super init]){
        tiles_ = [NSMutableArray array];
        tileClosed = NO;
    }
    return self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) initTile : (Tile *) sender
{
    int MINE_COUNT = 16;
    for(int i = 0; i < MINE_COUNT; i++){
        while(1){
            int rand = random() % [tiles_ count];
            Tile * tile = [tiles_ objectAtIndex:rand];
            if(tile != sender && !tile.isMine){
                tile.isMine = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    tileClosed = YES;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    NSLog( @"drawRect:" );

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
      // shrink into upper left quadrant
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];          // get view's location and size
    CGFloat w = CGRectGetWidth( bounds );   // w = width of view (in points)
    CGFloat h = CGRectGetHeight ( bounds ); // h = height of view (in points)
    dw = w/16.0f;                           // dw = width of cell (in points)
    dh = h/16.0f;                           // dh = height of cell (in points)

    NSLog( @"view (width,height) = (%g,%g)", w, h );
    NSLog( @"cell (width,height) = (%g,%g)", dw, dh );   

    // draw lines to form a 16x16 cell grid
    CGContextBeginPath( context );               // begin collecting drawing operations
        for ( int i = 1;  i < 16;  ++i )
    {
        // draw horizontal grid line
        CGContextMoveToPoint( context, 0, i*dh );
        CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, w, i*dh );

    }
    for ( int i = 1;  i < 16;  ++i )
    {
        // draw vertical grid line
        CGContextMoveToPoint( context, i*dw, 0 );
        CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, i*dw, h );
    }
    for(int x=1; x<16;x++){
        for(int y=1;y<16;y++){

            Tile * tile = [[Tile alloc] init];
            [tile setFrame:CGRectMake(x * 16.0f, y * 16.0f, 16.0f, 16.0f)];
            [tile addTarget:self action:@selector(clickCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [tiles_ addObject: tile];        }

    }
    [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];             // use gray as stroke color
    CGContextDrawPath( context, kCGPathStroke ); // execute collected drawing ops

}

- (void) clickCell : (Tile *) sender
{
    if(! tileClosed) [self initTile: sender];
    [sender open];
}
```

Comment: Also, are there any simple guides / tutorials for learning the basics of UIView?

Comment: What is the definition of Tile?

Comment: Btw, don't name any method to start with 'init' unless it's actually an init method. Your initTile ignores this and so breaks the Cocoa Touch method naming conventions.

Comment: Read the UIView docs, try searching for UIView tutorial.

Comment: "based off" isn't enough. Post actual source if you want help!

Comment: This is what I have right now for the Tile. Not much different than the base, just a few changed values.http://codepad.org/glTL3GcY

Answer (score 0):

Your `initwithFrame:` method is broken: the return line should just be `return self;`.

What you're doing at the moment in effect clobbers the `tiles_` array, so it ends up as nil, hence attempting to store tiles in it does nothing (and hence they aren't retained).

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the buttons. It seems like there are multiple wrongs in my implementation. Ugh, I wish there was just some clear cut universal way to make buttons.

Comment: I am still having the same problem. I am trying to click at different spots on the grid, but there is nothing indicating the buttons actually exist

Answer (score 0):

Your init method is incorrect and you can change it simply to

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
      {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame]
        if( self)
        {
          tiles_ = [NSMutableArray array];
          tileClosed = NO;
        }
        return self;
      }
```

and for the buttons to be appearing you are not adding it to the subview the

```
    [self.view addSubview:tile];
```

is missing.

Comment: The second line of self.view gives me a compiler error. Property 'view' was not found on object MyView.

Comment: I also tried this `MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];`, but still have the same error

Comment: Your class is a subclass of UIView so just add the view as follows  [self addSubview:title], the above one [self.view addSubview:title] is if you are adding it to the view of the controller.